# VBA Can't transpose data (Copying from one workbook to a closed book)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code that will copy data from one workbook and save it to a closed book.  The problem is that I need the data transposed from columns to rows.  I have tried paste specials but they did not work.  Below is the code I used that will at least transfer the data from the active sheet to the closed one.

```
Sub LessonLearned()

  Dim destSht As Worksheet

  Workbooks.Open Filename:="C:\Users\ceasat28\Documents\LessonsLearnedTest\LessonsLearnedLog.xlsx"
  Set destSht = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DiscoveredLessons") 

  ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="Secret"

  With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 

    With .Range(.Range("LL_Data"), .Range("LL_Data").End(xlDown)) 

      destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value 

    End With

    destSht.Parent.Close True 
  End With
End Sub
```

Can someone please help me transpose the values?

Thanks,
Tara

Comment: I feel like you would have to loop cell by cell, writing the data from one, to the other but swapping a row counter for a column counter when you do.

Comment: Quick workaround... after data is in sheet use the worksheet function: `Range("A1:E1") = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("A3:A7"))` Note that you'll have to know your range before and after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of issues:

- You need to actually transpose the data
- You need to correctly size the destination range based on the transposed source range

---

```
Sub LessonLearned()
    Dim destWb As Workbook
    Dim destSht As Worksheet
    Dim Data As Variant

    Set destWb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Users\ceasat28\Documents\LessonsLearnedTest\LessonsLearnedLog.xlsx")
    Set destSht = destWb.Worksheets("DiscoveredLessons")

    destSht.Unprotect Password:="Secret"

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        With .Range(.Range("LL_Data"), .Range("LL_Data").End(xlDown))
            Data = Application.Transpose(.Value)
            destSht.Cells(destSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(.Columns.Count, .Rows.Count).Value = Data
        End With
        destSht.Parent.Close True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked amazingly. Thank you so much, I have been trying this for a week!